# Подскажите, что означает данная запись?

Tags: ассемблер

```
var_7C= dword ptr -7Ch 
var_70= byte ptr -70h 
var_68= byte ptr -68h 
var_60= byte ptr -60h 
var_5C= dword ptr -5Ch 
var_58= byte ptr -58h 
var_54= dword ptr -54h 
var_50= dword ptr -50h 
var_4C= dword ptr -4Ch 
var_48= byte ptr -48h 
var_38= dword ptr -38h 
var_34= dword ptr -34h 
var_30= dword ptr -30h 
var_20= dword ptr -20h 
var_1C= dword ptr -1Ch 
Buffer= byte ptr -18h 
var_17= byte ptr -17h 
var_16= byte ptr -16h 
var_15= byte ptr -15h 
var_14= byte ptr -14h 
var_13= byte ptr -13h 
var_12= byte ptr -12h 
var_11= byte ptr -11h 
var_4= dword ptr -4
```

Comment: В таком виде ничего не означает. Всё зависит, от куда вы взяли эти данные.

Comment: Это вывод IDA Pro. Означает - какие переменные (предположительно) используются в процедуре и их смещения в стеке относительно начала стекового кадра процедуры (обычно это значение регистра EBP).